# Convert cv::mat to QImage using QImage::loadFromData

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qimage

I’ve found similar topics but not this particular one. Any ideas what’s wrong with the following code? It returns ‘loaded=false’, which obviously means that image data cannot be loaded.

```
cv::Mat mymat;
QImage qimg;
mymat = cv::imread("C:\\testimages\\img1.png");
int len = mymat.total()*mymat.elemSize();
bool loaded = qimg.loadFromData((uchar*)mymat.data, len, "PNG");
```

Thank you!

Comment: You may wanna use an open source implementation regarding the qimage-cv::mat conversion issue: https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtOpenCV/blob/master/cvmatandqimage.cpp. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The `cv::Mat` type holds a decoded image. Thus you cannot ask `QImage` to decode it again using the `loadFromData()` method.

You need to set up an image with format matching the element type, retrieved using `Mat::type()`, then either copy the raw data from the matrix to the image, or set up a `QImage` header for the data. In OpenCV terminology, a "header" means an object that doesn't hold its own data.

The code below sets up a header `QImage`.

```
QMap<int, QImage::Format> fmtMap;
fmtMap.insert(CV8_UC4, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
fmtMap.insert(CV_8UC3, QImage::Format_RGB888)
// We should convert to a color image since 8-bit indexed images can't be painted on
cv::Mat mat = cv::imread("C:\\testimages\\img1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Q_ASSERT(fmtMap.contains(cvImage.type());
Q_ASSERT(mat.isContinuous());
QImage img(cvImage.data, cvImage.cols, cvImage.rows, fmtMap[cvImage.type()]);
// The matrix *must* outlive the image, otherwise the image will access a dangling pointer to data
```

It may be easier to load the image using `QImage`, and then create a header matrix for it.

```
QMap<QImage::Format, int> fmtMap;
fmtMap.insert(QImage::Format_ARGB32, CV8_UC4);
fmtMap.insert(QImage::Format_RGB32, CV8_UC4);
fmtMap.insert(QImage::Format_RGB888, CV_8UC3);
QImage img;
img.load("C:\\testimages\\img1.png");
Q_ASSERT(fmtMap.contains(img.format()));
cv::Mat mat(img.height(), img.width(), fmtMap[img.format()], img.bits());
// The image *must* outlive the matrix, otherwise the matrix will access a dangling pointer to data
```

Comment: Thanks for this info! I had a success to load the image using the constructor of 'QImage' similar to what you suggested: but I wanted to use the 'loadFromData()' method.

Comment: You can't use `loadFromData()` since it doesn't do what you want to do. What you want, if you indeed care to make `QImage` a copy of the `Mat`, is pretty much a `memcpy` into the `bits()`.

Comment: Little Typo in the map: CV8_UC4 should be CV_8UC4. Trivia-Question: What would the inverted Map look like, how to see the difference in 0x**rrggbb and 0xrrggbb**.